# Pandas: Drop Rows, Columns If More Than Half Are NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame called `df` with 1,460 rows and 81 columns.  I want to remove all columns where at least half the entries are NaN and to do something similar for rows.

From the Pandas docs, I attempted this:

```
train_df.shape //(1460, 81)
train_df.dropna(thresh=len(train_df)/2, axis=1, inplace=True)
train_df.shape //(1460, 77)
```

Is this the correct way of doing it?  It seems to remove 4 columns but I'm surprised.  I would have thought `len(train_df)` gets me the number of rows so I've passed the wrong value to `thresh`...?

How would I do the same thing for rows (removing rows where at least half the columns are NaN)?

Thanks!

Comment: you are on the right trend , train_df.dropna(thresh=train_df.shape[0]/2, axis=0, inplace=True)

Comment: @Wen Your code is for removing rows or columns?

Comment: That is for row

Comment: Your results will be different if you remove rows first than if you remove columns first and different yet again if you evaluate both rows and columns before removing either.

Answer (score 7):

I guess you did the right thing but forgot to add the .index.
The line should look like this:

```
train_df.dropna(thresh=len(train_df.index)/2, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Juan, welcome to SO.  Thank you for your well written answer, this is exactly what we need more of!

Answer (score 5):

Using `count` and `loc`. `count(axis=)` ignores `NaN`s for counting.

```
In [4135]: df.loc[df.count(1) > df.shape[1]/2, df.count(0) > df.shape[0]/2]
Out[4135]:
          0
0  0.382991
1  0.428040
7  0.441113
```

---

Details

```
In [4136]: df
Out[4136]:
          0         1         2         3
0  0.382991  0.658090  0.881214  0.572673
1  0.428040  0.258378  0.865269  0.173278
2  0.579953       NaN       NaN       NaN
3  0.117927       NaN       NaN       NaN
4  0.597632       NaN       NaN       NaN
5  0.547839       NaN       NaN       NaN
6  0.998631       NaN       NaN       NaN
7  0.441113  0.527205  0.779821  0.251350

In [4137]: df.count(1) > df.shape[1]/2
Out[4137]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7     True
dtype: bool

In [4138]: df.count(0) < df.shape[0]/2
Out[4138]:
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: I like the use of `count` cleverly skipping nulls.  This was a little long to put in a comment, eh?

Comment: Actually, I like the use of `mean > 0.5` skipping `shape`. Grass is always greener on the other side I suppose ;)

Comment: Nope!  pretty green on both sides I'd say (-:

Answer (score 2):

**Setup**

```
np.random.seed([3,14159])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([1, np.nan], size=(10, 10)))

df

     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
0  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN
1  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0
2  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0
3  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN
4  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN
5  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0
6  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0
7  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
8  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0
9  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

---

**Solution 1**
This assumes you make the calculation for rows and columns before you drop either rows or columns.

```
n = df.notnull()

df.loc[n.mean(1) > .5, n.mean() > .5]

     5    6    9
1  1.0  1.0  1.0
4  1.0  NaN  NaN
8  NaN  1.0  1.0
9  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

---

**Solution 2**
Similar concept but using `numpy` tools.

```
v = np.isnan(df.values)

r = np.count_nonzero(v, 1) < v.shape[1] // 2
c = np.count_nonzero(v, 0) < v.shape[0] // 2
df.loc[r, c]

     5    6    9
1  1.0  1.0  1.0
4  1.0  NaN  NaN
8  NaN  1.0  1.0
9  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, it would do !

`df.dropna(thresh = df.shape[1]/3, axis = 0, inplace = True)`